# How to update a document with new attribute

Tags: python, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB in order to update a document with a new attribute.

My steps are as follows:

1. Get the document and store it in a variable

   `doc = self.db.get_document(document_name="document_name")`
2. Iterate over the doc, and add to it the attribute, for e.g.:

   ```
        for idx, movie in enumerate(doc):

            print(movie)

            query = 'UPSERT { movie_id: @movie_id, scene_element: @scene_element}  INSERT\
                { movie_id: @movie_id, scene_element: @scene_element, index: @index, \
                    _key: @_key, _id: @_id, _rev: @_rev, url_path: @url_path, captions: @captions, ref: @ref, \
                    experts: @experts, groundtruth: @groundtruth, base: @base, source: @source, File: @File } UPDATE \
                {   index: @index \
                } IN document_name'

            movie["index"] = idx
            self.pdb.aql.execute(query, bind_vars=movie)
   ```

And this works, **I'm trying to use this query differently without the `INSERT` command. Why something like this doesn't work:**

```
query = 'UPSERT { movie_id: @movie_id, scene_element: @scene_element}  UPDATE \
                    {   index: @index \
                    } IN document_name'
```

Finding the correct movie_id and scene_element, and just updating it with new index.

The error I'm getting is invalid syntax, and it asks for me to put the `INSERT` command.

Comment: Because UPSERT is supposed to _either_ UPATE an existing document, _or_, if no matching document exists, INSERT one. What exactly are you trying to do? Update a document _iff_ it exists and otherwise simply do nothing?

Comment: @mpoeter I'm trying to iterate over the document and add an additional attribute called `index` to every entry I have there. And I don't understand why do I need to explicitly write all it's attributes in the `INSERT` in order to achieve that..

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE`, not `UPSERT` if you don't want to use UPSERTs feature of either updating OR inserting